# Escaping invalid XML characters (e.g. for the Java DOM API)

Tags: java, xml, dom, escaping

I want to save and load an arbitrary Java `String` in a `Text` node in a XML file using the Java DOM API.

The `Transformer` and the `DocumentBuilder` already escape and unescape predefined entities such as `"`, `&`, `'`, `<`, `>` and a few other characters by replacing them with with `&quot;`, `&amp;`, `&apos;`, `&lt;`, `&gt;` and `&#c;`, where `c` is the Unicode code point.

So this is not the kind of escaping I am talking about. I am talking about the characters which are not in the ranges #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF] because these are according to the XML specifications invalid characters in XML files, even if escaped.

However, I want to be able to save an arbitrary `String` which may or may not contains an invalid character. The idea is to use two functions `escapeInvalidXmlCharacters` and `unescapeInvalidXmlCharacters` before and after using the DOM API as in the following example. Invalid characters are replaced by `#c;`, where `c` is the Unicode code point and `#` is escaped by a leading `#`.

```java
    // should not be reviewed
    String string = "text#text##text#0;text" + '\u0000' + "text<text&text#";
    Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
    Element element = document.createElement("element");
    element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(escapeInvalidXmlCharacters(string)));
    document.appendChild(element);
    TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(new File("test.xml")));
    // creates <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><element>text##text####text##0;text#0;text&lt;text&amp;text##</element>
    document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new File("test.xml"));
    System.out.println(unescapeInvalidXmlCharacters(document.getDocumentElement().getTextContent()).equals(string));
    // prints true
```

Here are the functions to be reviewed.

```java
    /**
     * Escapes invalid XML Unicode code points in a <code>{@link String}</code>. The
     * DOM API already escapes predefined entities, such as {@code "}, {@code &},
     * {@code '}, {@code <} and {@code >} for
     * <code>{@link org.w3c.dom.Text Text}</code> nodes. Therefore, these Unicode
     * code points are ignored by this function. However, there are some other
     * invalid XML Unicode code points, such as {@code '\u0000'}, which are even
     * invalid in their escaped form, such as {@code "&#0;"}.
     * <p>
     * This function replaces all {@code '#'} by {@code "##"} and all Unicode code
     * points which are not in the ranges #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] |
     * [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF] by the <code>{@link String}</code>
     * {@code "#c;"}, where <code>c</code> is the Unicode code point.
     * 
     * @param string the <code>{@link String}</code> to be escaped
     * @return the escaped <code>{@link String}</code>
     * @see <code>{@link #unescapeInvalidXmlCharacters(String)}</code>
     */
    public static String escapeInvalidXmlCharacters(String string) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0, codePoint = 0; i < string.length(); i += Character.charCount(codePoint)) {
            codePoint = string.codePointAt(i);

            if (codePoint == '#') {
                stringBuilder.append("##");
            } else if (codePoint == 0x9 || codePoint == 0xA || codePoint == 0xD || codePoint >= 0x20 && codePoint <= 0xD7FF || codePoint >= 0xE000 && codePoint <= 0xFFFD || codePoint >= 0x10000 && codePoint <= 0x10FFFF) {
                stringBuilder.appendCodePoint(codePoint);
            } else {
                stringBuilder.append("#" + codePoint + ";");
            }
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Unescapes invalid XML Unicode code points in a <code>{@link String}</code>.
     * Makes <code>{@link #escapeInvalidXmlCharacters(String)}</code> undone.
     * 
     * @param string the <code>{@link String}</code> to be unescaped
     * @return the unescaped <code>{@link String}</code>
     * @see <code>{@link #escapeInvalidXmlCharacters(String)}</code>
     */
    public static String unescapeInvalidXmlCharacters(String string) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        boolean escaped = false;

        for (int i = 0, codePoint = 0; i < string.length(); i += Character.charCount(codePoint)) {
            codePoint = string.codePointAt(i);

            if (escaped) {
                stringBuilder.appendCodePoint(codePoint);
                escaped = false;
            } else if (codePoint == '#') {
                StringBuilder intBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                int j;

                for (j = i + 1; j < string.length(); j += Character.charCount(codePoint)) {
                    codePoint = string.codePointAt(j);

                    if (codePoint == ';') {
                        escaped = true;
                        break;
                    }

                    if (codePoint >= 48 && codePoint <= 57) {
                        intBuilder.appendCodePoint(codePoint);
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (escaped) {
                    try {
                        codePoint = Integer.parseInt(intBuilder.toString());
                        stringBuilder.appendCodePoint(codePoint);
                        escaped = false;
                        i = j;
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        codePoint = '#';
                        escaped = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    codePoint = '#';
                    escaped = true;
                }
            } else {
                stringBuilder.appendCodePoint(codePoint);
            }
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
```

You can additionally post your answer under my related SO question https://stackoverflow.com/q/59447599/3882565 where I have started a +200 reputation bounty.

Comment: How would an answer that is acceptable here be acceptable on SO?

Comment: @FreezePhoenix Just wanted to link this question here and if someone has some major improvements, why shouldn't they be posted on SO too? Of course not in the form of a review, but rather as a finished version. If you don't think your answer is acceptable on SO, then just don't post it there.